# Object Oriented Database Connection

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to connect to my local host for a class I am in.  I have not been able to resolve these errors I have been having.  Can any one help?  Here is the code.

```
class mymysqli {
    public $db;
    function connectdb ($hostname, $database, $mysqli_login, $mysqli_password){
        $db=mysqli_connect ($hostname, $mysqli_login, $mysqli_password) or die     ('There is an issue');
        mysqli_select_db($database, 'conectdb');
        return $db;
    }
    function selectRows ($query){
        $resultSet=mysqli_query($query);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($resultSet) > 0){
            return $resultSet;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}

$DBConnect = new mymysqli();
$db=$DBConnect->connectdb("localhost","nwtip","root","");
if($db){
    $SQL = "SELECT color FROM colors ORDER BY color";
    $rs = $DBConnect -> selectRows($SQL);
    if ($rs){
        $intcount=0;
        while(mysqli_fetch_row($rs)){
            echo mysqli_result($rs,$intcount,"color")."<br>";
            $intcount++;
        }
    }
}
```

These are the errors
Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in C:\wamp\www\inclass.php on line 10

Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\wamp\www\inclass.php on line 14

Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\wamp\www\inclass.php on line 15

Answer (score 1):

```
$db=mysqli_connect ($hostname, $mysqli_login, $mysqli_password) or die
```

$db is not being set first off due to scope

```
mysqli_select_db($database, 'conectdb');
```

should read

```
mysqli_select_db($db, 'conectdb');
```